# Update after select mysql

Tags: mysql

How do i update one table after I selected values from 4 other tables:

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM racunala) as racunala, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM objekti) as objekti,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM programi) as programi,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users) as korisnici,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tvrtke) as tvrtke
```

I have another table called "cumulative" and i want to update that table based on query above.

```
UPDATE `info`.`cumulative` SET `korisnici`=korisnici, `tvrtke`=tvrtke, `objekti`=objekti, `programi`=programi, `racunala`=racunala WHERE `idcumulative`='1';
```

I want  to make a single stored procedure which will update all the data in "cumulative" table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like that

```
UPDATE
    `info`.`cumulative`
SET
    `korisnici`= ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM users ),
    `tvrtke`= ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM tvrtke ),
    `objekti`= ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM objekti ),
    `programi`= ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM programi ),
    `racunala`= ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM racunala )
WHERE
    `idcumulative`='1';
```

You can combine it with WHERE conditions

```
UPDATE
    `info`.`cumulative`
SET
    `korisnici`= ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM users WHERE users.X = info.X ),
    `tvrtke`= ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM tvrtke WHERE tvrtke.X = info.X ),
    `objekti`= ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM objekti WHERE objekti.X = info.X ),
    `programi`= ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM programi WHERE programi.X = info.X ),
    `racunala`= ( SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM racunala WHERE racunala.X = info.X )
WHERE
    `idcumulative`='1';
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. That's exactly what i needed